# How to call (line-end-position) that returns a value excluding trailing whitespace?

Tags: whitespace

What is a good way to replace `(line-end-position)` with a function that doesn't include trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an argument, `(line-end-position)` is functionally equivalent to `(save-excursion (end-of-line) (point))`.  Armed with that knowledge, your custom function could be defined as follows:

```elisp
(defun my-line-end-position ()
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-line)
    (skip-syntax-backward "-")
    (point)))
```